# While Loop Issue: Does not pause

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I made some kind of mistake in this loop, and I really can't figure it out. Here's the loop:

```
while (true) {
        System.out.print(stepName[currentTick]);

        for(int i = stepName[currentTick].length() - longestNameInt; i == 0; i--)
            System.out.print(" ");

        System.out.print(" [");

        double percentCalc = (double) stepPercent[currentTick];
        int slotsRep = (int) Math.round((percentCalc * 0.2));

        for(int i = slotsRep; i == 0; i--)
            System.out.print("*");

        for(int i = 20 - slotsRep; i == 0; i--)
            System.out.print(" ");

        System.out.print("] " + stepPercent[currentTick] + "% \r");

        if(currentTick == totalTicks)
            break;

        Thread.sleep(stepTime[currentTick]);
    }
```

Basically, it just keeps printing '(First stepname) [*] 0%' rapidly.
I'm sorry if it's super obvious, but I'm kinda a noob. :)

P.S. Please ask me if you need more of my class.

Comment: Can you mention the expected value of current tick and totalticks, as may be it can happen that they will nvr break and your loop goes infinite

Comment: In case any solution solves your problem than accept answers on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a infinite `while` loop here.

```
if(currentTick == totalTicks)
    break;
```

You don't seem to be changing the values of either `currentTick` or `totalTicks` at all but the `break` from the `while` loop is supposed to happen when both the above 2 values are equal. Since they are not equal initially and you never change them in the `while`, it becomes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

Please change this :

```
for(int i = stepName[currentTick].length() - longestNameInt; i == 0; i--)
```

TO

```
for(int i = stepName[currentTick].length() - longestNameInt; i >= 0; i--)
```

only comparison mistake is there.

Also make it sure that value of `current tick or totalticks changes for the loop to break`, as may be it can happen that they will never achive the equality state and your loop goes infinite because of `while(true)` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Make following corrections

1. `for(int i = stepName[currentTick].length() - longestNameInt; i >= 0;`
           i--)

   ```
    2.    `for(int i = slotsRep; i >= 0; i--)

     3.  `for(int i = 20 - slotsRep; i == 0; i--)`
   ```